# What is await with question mark (await?) in Rust?

Tags: rust, error-handling, async-await

I read this portion of the book on Async programming in Rust https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html

I see the mention of the `.await` syntax,

and then I later saw a blog where `reqwest` is being used to fetch a url. The code looks like this:

```
let resp200 = client.get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
    .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
    .send()
    .await?
    .json::<GETAPIResponse>()
    .await?;
```

I do not understand the `.await?`. I know `?` is a shorthand for extracting the `Ok` case or returning from the function with an Error. But as far as I am aware, `.await` does not return `Result` so how is it possible to do `.await` with `?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.await` simply turns a `impl Future<Output = T>` into a `T`.

`?` (mostly) turns a `Result<T, E>` into a `T`.

When put together, `.await?` turns a `impl Future<Output = Result<T, E>>` into a `T`.

The following code is equivalent:

```rust
let future = client.get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
    .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
    .send();
let result: Result<_, _> = future.await;
let response: Response = result?;
let json_future = response.json();
let json_response: Result<_, _> = json_future.await;
let json = json_response?;
```

But, `.await?` is not a special operator. It's literally just `.await` followed by `?`

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on how `?` is used, and you are correct in that `.await` does not inherently return `Result`, but in this case and most cases it does, because the .send() is an IO operation, if you look at the `blocking::reqwest` api you will find that .send() returns a Result
To summarize, the `?` is not for the `.await` itself, but for what `.await` returned.

```
let result: Result = client.get().send().await;
let send_response = result?;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's two separated things in fact `await` and `?`, await returns Furture, which is being unwrapped by by `?`.

The question mark `?` operator in Rust is used as an error propagation alternative to functions that return Result or Option types. The `?` operator is a shortcut as it reduces the amount of code needed to immediately return `Err` or `None` from the types `Result<T, Err>` or Option in a function.